# Can I root my Cube Talk7x (U51GT-C8) without installing new ROM?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting

I need to root my device:

- Device name: Cube Talk7x (U51GT-C8)
- CPU: MT8392 (quad-core)
- Android version: 4.4.2 Kitkat
- Kernel version: 3.4.64

The reasons for rooting:

- I want to use APP2SD with external SD card (on my previous device, which was rooted, I've *swapped* `/storage/sdcard0` and `/storage/sdcard1`)
- I want to mount it with SSHFS (it works, but SSH server can't access external SD card)

I have no MS-Windows machine, but if it's necessary, I can borrow one.

Answer (score 1):

ern0, there is a website that has a download to root this device and it looks like you can do it from the device itself.

If you download http://www.jellydroid.com/framaroot-1-9-0-apk/Framaroot-1.9.0.apk and install it then select install “SuperSU“ and select an exploit in list to potentially root your device as “Barahir” and proceed further.

You should see a success message and then reboot. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it's not working, neither method.

Answer (score 1):

I think so you should borrow one MS-Windows machine. If you want to root device properly you should have a MS-Windows machine!
If you got a MS-Windows machine Download [iRoot](http://www.mgyun.com/en/getvroot). Install iRoot. Enable USB Debugging Mode in your device. Install Device Drivers on your machine and connect your device to machine. Your machine should be connected to internet while rooting your device.Connect device with USB. In root Tab, Click on root Device. Restart Your Cube Talk7x. This should work from my information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's weird I would say you would have got the device rooted using Framaroot, double cross check if you are using the latest version of the Framaroot to root your device?? I somewhere doubt that you are trying to do the same with older version of the Farmaroot, anyway I think it would be better for you to try doing that again using the latest version of  [Framaroot 1.9.3 over here](http://www.apkhere.com/app/com.alephzain.framaroot).